# Use different keyboard inputs

Tags: java, android

I have two button one for arabic and one for English. I want that when user click on Arabic button i show arabic keyboard and when English button clicked. English keyboard should appear to put text in edit text how it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this app use in Arabic country then you can try show language choice dialog using following code.

```
private void showLanguagePicker() {
    InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imeManager != null) {
        imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your btn.onClickListner try this

```
String languageToLoad  = "en"; // your language
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics())
```

en for English, ru for Russian etc. Actually don't know Arabic keyword